# django ListView query_set code abbreviation

Tags: python, django, listview, inner-join, django-queryset

> The codes are as

**models.py**

```
class Firm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, verbose_name="Firma Adı")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=50)


class Worksite(models.Model):
    firm = models.ForeignKey('Firm', verbose_name='Firma', related_name="worksites", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50, verbose_name="Şantiye Adı")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=50)


class Subcontractor(models.Model):
    worksite = models.ForeignKey('Worksite', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firm = models.ForeignKey('Firm', related_name="subcontractors", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

> Can the queryset code be written shorter?

**views.py**

```
class SubcontractorListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'firm/subcontractor_list.html'
    context_object_name = "firms"
    def get_queryset(self):
        ws = self.request.user.firm.worksites.values_list('id', flat=True)
        ss = Subcontractor.objects.values_list('firm_id', flat=True).filter(worksite_id__in=ws)
        return Firm.objects.filter(id__in=ss)
```

> Do you have different and short solutions?

**template**

```
{% for firm in firms %}
    <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary text-left button">{{ firm }} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The company model has two types of companies. Parent company and subcontractor firm. The worksite model is already standard. Things get a little confused in the subcontractor model. When the firm adds a subcontractor to the worksite model.The subcontractor is added to the firm model as a firm. The subcontractor model, the "firm_id" field takes the value of the subcontractor firm's "id". The "worksite_id" field is the id of the worksite to which the subcontractor is attached. "queryset" was created according to this logic. I want shorter and different solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the summary description of "queryset".
AAA company added a building site named BBB. The AAA company then added a subcontractor named CCC to the BBB worksite. The CCC subcontractor is a company at the same time. Then the AAA firm wants to list the subcontractor firm attached to the construction site. The "firm_id" field in the "subcontractor" table is linked to the subcontractor firm "id". The parent company is listing according to the worksite in the "subcontractor" table.

Comment: [GITHUB LINK worksite management and tracking system](https://github.com/mstgnz/worksite)

Comment: What is this view trying to show? All the firms that are on a specific worksite?

Comment: Each firm can have more than one worksite. Every workplace can also be a subcontractor. Here we are extracting the worksite listing of the firm that entered the system. According to the list, subcontractors are listed. It's a bit complicated.

Comment: Firma tablosu bütün firmalara ait tablodur. Bir ana firmanın birden fazla şantiyesi olabilir. Her şantiyenin de bir ana firması bir de taşeron firmaları vardır. Ana firma ile taşeron firma bağlantısını sağlayan subcontractor tablosudur. ana firmanın şantiye ID'si ile taşeron firmanın ID'sini tutar.